# How to get value from list using index?

Tags: python-2.7, function, loops, odoo-10, enumerate

I have to try to get one by one value from list using index and i have try to get index value and update my stage one by one and respectively.

**my python code below :**

```
for ress in status_list:
    print"res", ress
    #self.workflow_stages = ress
    if ress:
        self.workflow_stages = ress
        for index, item in enumerate(status_list):
            print "test::", index
            index_init = index
            print"index_init:::", index_init
            next = index_init + 1
            print "next", next
            lent = len(status_list)
            print"lent", lent
        return True
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This `for index, item in enumerate(status_list):` means that `index` variable holds your respective index of the `status_list` and `item` variable holds your value. So in given `for` loop, `item` will hold the value of the corresponding `index.`

Generally, if you don't use the `enumerate` functionality to iterate over a list, you can access a value of the list like this `status_list[index]`